# Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, python, json, selenium, automation

I am using this to add html between a div tag but it displays `Unexpected token '<'`

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = " + f'{x["solution"]}', solution)
```

The `x["solution"]` is a json file which contains html like `<strong> bold </strong>` etc.

Comment: `<strong> bold <\strong>` shouldn't be `<strong> bold </strong>`???

Comment: I recently ran into a similar problem. I had to use symbol codes and unescape().

Comment: @WasifHasan Yes sir, i sometimes get confused about the slashes :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to quote the right part of the equality. This code is generating:

```js
arguments[0].innerHTML = <strong> bold </strong>
```

Also, you can use a single formatted string which would look like:

```py
browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{x["solution"]}"', solution)
```

and would generate

```js
arguments[0].innerHTML = "<strong> bold </strong>"
```